# AVPlayerItem load with a unknown file extension (cached file)

Tags: ios, swift, caching, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a Caching Class that downloads MP3 files to some cachefolder and names it `xxxx.cache`

I have a  AVQueuePlayer that loads MP3 files. loading/queueing MP3 files  from my NSBundle Resources folder works fine (using `AVPlayerItem` using `AVQueuePlayer.insertItem(item, afterItem:nil)`.

But, I cannot load a `xxxx.cache` file into my AVQueuePlayer using its filePath into this AVPlayerAsset, because I think it cannot recognize its file extension...

I know that `AVAudioPlayer` works, but that doesn't have queueing functionality (which I need badly)

Someone maybe knows how to force load as MP3 into AVPlayerItem maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Cache the relative URL. When fetching the cached URL, construct the URL as you would a brand new one give a relative URL. iOS doesn't gauranteethe container name to stay the same so you end up loading nothing